# Setting new body position on BeginContact event

Tags: javascript, box2d

I want to set a new position of body on BeginContact event but it's still not functional. It's writed in JavaSript with drawing to canvas but it doesn't matter for Box2d. In HTML file in body is only empty canvas, nothing else. Here is my code:

In the beginning of JS file are only declarated some variables.

```
Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;
BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef;
Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body;
FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef;
Fixture = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture;
World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World;
PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape;
DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw;

var player;
```

It's followed by a setup function which is called in the beginning.

```
function setup()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("collisionCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";

    canvas.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 320;

    world = new World(new Vec2(0, 10), false);

    //Point of the problem!!!
    //setting contact listener
    var listener = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
    listener.BeginContact = function(contact)
    {
        var body1 = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody();
        var body2 = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody();

        if(body1.GetUserData().type == "player")
        {
            body1.SetPosition({x:5, y:5});
        }
        else
        {
            body2.SetPosition({x:5, y:5});
        }
    }
    world.SetContactListener(listener);

    var fixDef = new FixtureDef;
    fixDef.density = 1.0;
    fixDef.friction = 0.5;
    fixDef.restitution = 0.2;

    var bodyDef = new BodyDef;

    //creating ground
    bodyDef.type = Body.b2_staticBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = convertPixelsToMeters(160);
    bodyDef.position.y = convertPixelsToMeters(320-32/2);
    bodyDef.userData = {type: "static"};
    fixDef.shape = new PolygonShape;
    fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(convertPixelsToMeters(canvas.width/2), convertPixelsToMeters(32/2));
    world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);

    //creating player
    bodyDef.type = Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    bodyDef.position.x = convertPixelsToMeters(160);
    bodyDef.position.y = convertPixelsToMeters(160);
    bodyDef.userData = {type: "player"};
    fixDef.shape = new PolygonShape;
    fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(convertPixelsToMeters(16), convertPixelsToMeters(16));
    player = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
    player.CreateFixture(fixDef);

    //setup debug draw
    var debugDraw = new DebugDraw();
    debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("collisionCanvas").getContext("2d"));
    debugDraw.SetDrawScale(32.0);
    debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.3);
    debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
    debugDraw.SetFlags(DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
    world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);

    window.setInterval(update, 1000 / 60);
}
```

And in the end are only update function, one helping function and that's it.

```
function update()
{
    world.Step(
        1 / 60   //frame-rate
        ,  10       //velocity iterations
        ,  10       //position iterations
    );
    world.DrawDebugData();
    world.ClearForces();
}

function convertPixelsToMeters(x)
{
    return x*0.03125;
}

$(function(){
    setup();
})
```

Important is only the middle code where is BeginContact event where is calling the SetPosition function which doesn't work.

I tried change position in other places, for example on KeyDown event and there it was correct, so it's for me understandable why it doesn't work.

Comment: I hope you understant what I want to say in my code and I think it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the b2Contactlistner method we can not change any prperty or position.

You can take any boolean variable and make it true when in beign contact and if change the position of body according to boolean variable.

as in your code.......
   var bodyyy;
var boolennn

```
listener.BeginContact = function(contact)
{
    var body1 = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody();
    var body2 = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody();

    if(body1.GetUserData().type == "player")
    {
        //body1.SetPosition({x:5, y:5});
       bodyyy = body1;
       booleannn = true;
    }
    else
    {
       // body2.SetPosition({x:5, y:5});
        bodyyy = body2;
        boolennn = true;
    }
}
```

Now In your Update method

```
if(booleann)
{
 bodyyy.SetPosition({x:5, y:5})
}
```

SORRY I Donot know syntax of java script

Comment: Man, you're right! I didn't know that I cannot change anything there. Thank's a lot!